# WUBI problem: when boot "no wubir"

Tags: boot, wubi, grub2

After re-installing ubuntu via wubi i now get "no wubir" and then directs me to a menu where i have to select which mode i want. Ubuntu is fine and wubi sees no problem. what do i do?

Comment: Can you boot into windows?

Comment: yes i can both windows and Ubuntu are fine its just wubi.

Comment: Did you get any errors,when you login into ubuntu?

Comment: I have the same problem and i get no other error.

Answer (score 1):

which version of windows are you using?
i tried to install ubuntu 10.10 as a dual boot on windows 7 and install went fine but got wubi error. 
i just booted from cd and used install alongside other os option and it worked ok from there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have dynamic partition in windows , make it simple ntfs and

put cd and run wubi.exe and follow the instructions and it will oinstal and after booting you get option to swioth either to window or to ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it says 'No wubir'? In the time I was using wubi, it always said 'No **wubildr**'. I never had any problems with it, by the way. The screen you see after this message is probably the GRUB bootloader, by the way.